# Firemonkey: Image.Bitmap.DrawLine not visible on ipad

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I'm building a app in DelphiXE2 firemonkey for IOS. If I tested on the mac in the Xcode IPAD Simulator I saw the button. But when I click on the button no line is visible. Why?

code: (On the Form a button and a Image)

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, Types, UITypes, Classes, Variants, FMX_Types, FMX_Controls, FMX_Forms,
  FMX_Dialogs, FMX_Objects;

type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    Image1: TImage;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var pt0,pt1 : TPointF;
begin
  pt0.Create(0,0);
  pt1.Create(200,200);
  with Image1.Bitmap do begin
    Canvas.Stroke.Color := $ffff0000 ;  // Red
    Canvas.BeginScene;

    Canvas.DrawLine(pt0,pt1,1);
    BitmapChanged;  // without this, no output
    Canvas.EndScene;
  end;

end;


procedure TForm3.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Image1.Bitmap := TBitmap.Create(200,200);
end;
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be:

```
pt0 := TPointF.Create(0, 0);
```

Comment: the same problem. no line appears.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  pt0.X:=X;
  pt0.Y:=Y;
  pt1.X:=X+4;
  pt1.Y:=Y+4;
  with Image1.Bitmap do begin
    Canvas.Stroke.Color := $ffff0000 ;  // Red
    Canvas.Stroke.Kind := TBrushKind.bkSolid;
    Canvas.StrokeThickness:= 10;
    Canvas.BeginScene;
    Canvas.DrawLine(pt0,pt1,100);
    Canvas.EndScene;
  end;
```